# Android/Java - Convert int values from a equation to double

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calculator

I'm creating a calculator app which works showing all the calculation steps in the screen, like this:

3x3x5/7*(3/2)

And then, the user just click in the "Enter" button to get the result.

The problem is that I'm always getting a integer value as a result, which is obvious, because I'm using integer values in the calculation (3, 5, 7, etc).
So, if I do this: 1/2, the result will be 0, but I want the answer to be 0.5

To be more specifcaly, this is how my calculator works:
The user hit the button 5, and it appears in the screen (a textview).
Then the user hit the button / (divide), using the append method, the screen now shows 5/, finaly the user hit the button 9, and the screen shows 5/9.
When the user hit "Enter", the app get the text from the screen and store it in a String variable, which will be used by the JEXL library (used to evaluate equations), giving me the result.

The problem is that, I want the numbers to appear in the screen as integer, so if I hit 9, I don't want it to appears as 9.0 in the screen, but there's another problem, imagine that I want to enter the number "93", I would firts hit 9, and 9.0 would appear, then I would hit 3, and 3.0 would appear, giving me the "number" 9.03.0, which don't exist and can't be used.

So, where's a way to convert integer numbers in a String expression to double?
Or, maybe, to get a double value from a integer calculation?

Here's my java files:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tv_screen;
    TextView tv_set1;
    TextView tv_set2;

    String screenEvaluation;
    Double screenCalculation;
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();

    static final String digits = "0123456789.*/-+^( )√(";
    static final String numbers = "0123456789";
    static final String operators = "*/-+";

    static final String shifteds = "B1";

    Boolean shiftPressed = false;
    Boolean userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;

    Solver solver = new Solver();

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("@###########");
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

    //String buttonPressed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /* REMOVE TITLE BAR */

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        /* REMOVE NOTIFICATION BAR (AKA FULL SCREEN) */

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
        df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(8);

        tv_screen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_screen);
        tv_set1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_set1);
        tv_set2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_set2);

        findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_5).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_6).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_7).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_8).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_9).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_0).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.button_multiply).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_divide).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_minus).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_sum).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button_root).setOnClickListener(this); 
        findViewById(R.id.button_power).setOnClickListener(this); 
        findViewById(R.id.button_bracket).setOnClickListener(this); 
        findViewById(R.id.button_more_less).setOnClickListener(this); 
        findViewById(R.id.button_dot).setOnClickListener(this); 

        findViewById(R.id.button_shift).setOnClickListener(this);     
        findViewById(R.id.button_enter).setOnClickListener(this); 
        findViewById(R.id.button_clear).setOnClickListener(this); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String buttonPressed = ((Button) v).getText().toString(); 

        if (digits.contains(buttonPressed)) {

            // digit was pressed
            if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

                if (buttonPressed.equals(".") && tv_screen.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
                    // ERROR PREVENTION
                    // Eliminate entering multiple decimals
                } else {

                    if (buttonPressed.equals("( )")) {

                        buttonPressed = "(";

                        if (tv_screen.getText().toString().contains("(")) {

                            buttonPressed = ")";

                        }

                    }

                    if (buttonPressed.equals("√")) {

                        buttonPressed = "√(";

                    }

                    if (operators.contains(buttonPressed)) {

                        tv_screen.append(".0" + buttonPressed);

                    } else {

                        tv_screen.append(buttonPressed);

                    }
                }

            } else {

                if (buttonPressed.equals(".")) {
                    // ERROR PREVENTION
                    // This will avoid error if only the decimal is hit before an operator, by placing a leading zero
                    // before the decimal
                    tv_screen.setText(0 + buttonPressed);
                } else {             

                    if (buttonPressed.equals("( )")) {

                    buttonPressed = "(";

                        if (tv_screen.getText().toString().contains("(")) {

                            buttonPressed = ")";

                        }

                    }

                    if (buttonPressed.equals("√")) {

                        buttonPressed = "√(";

                    }
                    tv_screen.setText(buttonPressed);
                }

                userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true;
            }

        } else if (buttonPressed.equals("SHIFT")) {

            if (shiftPressed == true) {

                shiftPressed = false;
                solver.setShift(false);
                tv_set1.setText("");

            } else {

                shiftPressed = true;    
                solver.setShift(true);
                tv_set1.setText("SHIFT");

            }

        } else if (buttonPressed.equals("ENTER")) {

            //solver.performEnterOperation(buttonPressed);
            //tv_screen.setText("DONE!");

            screenEvaluation = tv_screen.getText().toString();
            //screenEvaluation = screenEvaluation.replace("x", "*");
            screenEvaluation = screenEvaluation.replace("√(", "SQRT(");
            Log.w("TAG", "thickness round:" + screenEvaluation);
            Expression e = jexl.createExpression(screenEvaluation);
            JexlContext context = new MapContext();
            String result = e.evaluate(context).toString();

            //Log.w("TAG", "thickness round:" + screenEvaluation);

            tv_screen.setText(result); 

            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;       

        } else if (shifteds.contains(buttonPressed) && shiftPressed == true) {

            tv_set2.setText(solver.getSetTextView(buttonPressed));

        } else if (buttonPressed.equals("CLEAR")) {

            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;

            tv_screen.setText("0");

        } else {        

            // operation was pressed
            if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

                //Log.w("TAG", "thickness round:" + yyy);

                tv_set2.setText(solver.getSetTextView(buttonPressed));

                solver.setOperand(Double.parseDouble(tv_screen.getText().toString()));
                userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;

            }

            //tv_set2.setText(solver.getSetTextView(buttonPressed));
            solver.performOperation(buttonPressed);
            tv_screen.setText(df.format(solver.getResult()));

        }

    }

}
```

And this one too, but isn't being used so far:

```
public class Solver {

    // 3 + 6 = 9
    // 3 & 6 are called the operand.
    // The + is called the operator.
    // 9 is the result of the operation.

    private double mOperand;
    private double mWaitingOperand;
    private String mWaitingOperator;
    private double mCalculatorMemory;

    private Boolean shift;

    private double pressure;
    private double inner_diameter;
    private double allowable_stress;
    private double weld_factor;
    private double y_factor;
    private double corrosion;

    // operator types
    public static final String ADD = "+";
    public static final String SUBTRACT = "-";
    public static final String MULTIPLY = "x";
    public static final String DIVIDE = "/";

    public static final String CLEAR = "C" ;
    public static final String CLEARMEMORY = "MC";
    public static final String ADDTOMEMORY = "M+";
    public static final String SUBTRACTFROMMEMORY = "M-";
    public static final String RECALLMEMORY = "MR";
    public static final String SQUAREROOT = "√";
    public static final String SQUARED = "x²";
    public static final String INVERT = "1/x";
    public static final String TOGGLESIGN = "+/-";
    public static final String SINE = "sin";
    public static final String COSINE = "cos";
    public static final String TANGENT = "tan";

    public static final String ARC = "ARC";
    public static final String B1 = "B1";
    public static final String B2 = "B2";
    public static final String B3 = "B3";
    public static final String B4 = "B4";
    public static final String B5 = "B5";
    public static final String B6 = "B6";

    // public static final String EQUALS = "=";

    // constructor
    public Solver() {
        // initialize variables upon start
        mOperand = 0;
        mWaitingOperand = 0;
        mWaitingOperator = "";
        mCalculatorMemory = 0;

        shift = false;

        pressure = 0;
        inner_diameter = 0;
        allowable_stress = 0;
        weld_factor = 0;
        y_factor = 0;
        corrosion = 0;
    }

    public void setOperand(double operand) {
        mOperand = operand;
    }

    public double getResult() {
        return mOperand;
    }

    // used on screen orientation change
    public void setMemory(double calculatorMemory) {
        mCalculatorMemory = calculatorMemory;
    }

    // used on screen orientation change
    public double getMemory() {
        return mCalculatorMemory;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Double.toString(mOperand);
    }

    public void setShift(Boolean shiftState) {      
        shift = shiftState;     
    }

    public void setPressure(double setPressure) {
        pressure = setPressure;
    }

    public void setInnerDiameter(double setInnerDiameter) {
        inner_diameter = setInnerDiameter;
    }

    public void setAllowableStress(double setAllowableStress) {
        allowable_stress = setAllowableStress;
    }

    public void setWeldFactor(double setWeldFactor) {
        weld_factor = setWeldFactor;
    }

    public void setYFactor(double setYFactor) {
        y_factor = setYFactor;
    }

    public void setCorrosion(double setCorrosion) {
        corrosion = setCorrosion;
    }

    public String getSetTextView(String setText) {  

        String text;

        if (setText.equals(ARC)) {          
            text = "PIPE";          
            return text;        
        } else if (setText.equals(B1)) {
            text = "PRESSURE";          
            return text;  
        } else if (setText.equals(B2)) {
            text = "INNER DIAMETER";        
            return text;        
        } else if (setText.equals(B3)) {
            text = "ALLOWABLE STRESS";          
            return text;  
        } else if (setText.equals(B4)) {
            text = "WELD FACTOR";           
            return text;  
        } else if (setText.equals(B5)) {
            text = "Y FACTOR";          
            return text;  
        } else if (setText.equals(B6)) {
            text = "CORROSION";
            return text;
        }

        text = "NADA";      
        return text; 

    }

    public double pipeThickness(double inner_pressure, double allowable_stress, double weld_factor, double inner_diameter, double corrosion, double y_factor) {     

        double thickness = ( ( inner_pressure * inner_diameter) + ( 2* allowable_stress * weld_factor * corrosion ) 
                + ( 2 * y_factor * inner_pressure * corrosion ) ) / ( 2* ( ( allowable_stress * weld_factor ) 
                + ( inner_pressure * y_factor ) - inner_pressure ) );

        return thickness;

    }

    protected void performEnterOperation(String operator) {

        if (shift == true) {

            if (operator.equals(B1)) {

                setPressure(mOperand);

            } 

        }

    }

    protected double performOperation(String operator) {

        /*
        * If you are using Java 7, then you can use switch in place of if statements
        *
        *     switch (operator) {
        *     case CLEARMEMORY:
        *         calculatorMemory = 0;
        *         break;
        *     case ADDTOMEMORY:
        *         calculatorMemory = calculatorMemory + operand;
        *         break;
        *     etc...
        *     }
        */

        if (shift == true) {

            if (operator.equals(ARC)) {

                getSetTextView(ARC);
                mOperand = 25.0;

            } 

        } else {

            if (operator.equals(CLEAR)) {
                mOperand = 0;
                mWaitingOperator = "";
                mWaitingOperand = 0;
                // mCalculatorMemory = 0;
            } else if (operator.equals(CLEARMEMORY)) {
                mCalculatorMemory = 0;
            } else if (operator.equals(ADDTOMEMORY)) {
                mCalculatorMemory = mCalculatorMemory + mOperand;
            } else if (operator.equals(SUBTRACTFROMMEMORY)) {
                mCalculatorMemory = mCalculatorMemory - mOperand;
            } else if (operator.equals(RECALLMEMORY)) {
                mOperand = mCalculatorMemory;
            } else if (operator.equals(SQUAREROOT)) {
                mOperand = Math.sqrt(mOperand);
            } else if (operator.equals(SQUARED)) {
                mOperand = mOperand * mOperand;
            } else if (operator.equals(INVERT)) {
                if (mOperand != 0) {
                    mOperand = 1 / mOperand;
                }
            } else if (operator.equals(TOGGLESIGN)) {
                mOperand = -mOperand;
            } else if (operator.equals(SINE)) {
                mOperand = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(mOperand)); // Math.toRadians(mOperand) converts result to degrees
            } else if (operator.equals(COSINE)) {
                mOperand = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(mOperand)); // Math.toRadians(mOperand) converts result to degrees
            } else if (operator.equals(TANGENT)) {
                mOperand = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(mOperand)); // Math.toRadians(mOperand) converts result to degrees                       
            } else {
                performWaitingOperation();
                mWaitingOperator = operator;
                mWaitingOperand = mOperand;
            }

        }

        return mOperand;        

    }

    protected void performWaitingOperation() {

        if (mWaitingOperator.equals(ADD)) {
            mOperand = mWaitingOperand + mOperand;
        } else if (mWaitingOperator.equals(SUBTRACT)) {
            mOperand = mWaitingOperand - mOperand;
        } else if (mWaitingOperator.equals(MULTIPLY)) {
            mOperand = mWaitingOperand * mOperand;
        } else if (mWaitingOperator.equals(DIVIDE)) {
            if (mOperand != 0) {
                mOperand = mWaitingOperand / mOperand;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Well, the solution that I found is this:

```
if (operators.contains(buttonPressed)) {    

                        tempNumber = Double.parseDouble(tv_screen.getText().toString().replace(tempString, ""));
                        equation = equation + tempNumber.toString() + buttonPressed;                    
                        tempString = tv_screen.getText().toString() + buttonPressed;

                    }
```

I created 3 variables:
Double tempNumber, which will get the values from the screen and store it as double.
String equation, which will store the equation as String with Double values, so, "9*3" will be "9.0*3.0".
String tempString, which is used to "clean" the tempNumber variable, replacing the "x", "/", and so on, with "" (nothing), so it'll convert only numbers to double.

Finaly, I'll instead of getting the equation from the screen textview, I'll get it from the equation variable:

```
tempNumber = Double.parseDouble(tv_screen.getText().toString().replace(tempString, ""));
equation = equation + tempNumber.toString(); 
Expression e = jexl.createExpression(equation);
JexlContext context = new MapContext();
String result = e.evaluate(context).toString();
```

Anyway, thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: If you really want to do a Calculator App you need to use BigDecimal instead of double :/, you will need to refactor some code but will do exactly what you want...

Comment: You might want to consider using the final String's you declared in your Solver class for operators (ie "√") instead of testing equality for them in the first class you posted. Much more readable, less chance of typos.

Comment: @GhostDerfel, thank you for your comment, I'll read about BigDecimal to see if it fits my needs.

Comment: @turbo, thank you, but I'll try to solve one problem at time! hehe

Comment: No problem, if you need help to understand something with BigDecimal just let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to parse the double from a string you can use

```
Double.parseDouble(sValue);
```

You can also use an explisit conversion in line for your equation so you can do something like:

```
(double)inum*(double)inum1*(double)inum2/(double)inum4*((double)inum5/(double)inum6)
```

and your result should then come out as a double instead of an integer.

Comment: I can't convert every number that the user hit because the following error will occur:
The user want to type "93". 
He will type "9" first, the app convert it to double, and then, "9.0" will appear in the screen.
Okay, now he type "3", the app convert it to double, and then, as the app uses the append method, the following will appear in the screen: "9.03.0".
Unfortunately I can't use Double.parseDouble() in a whole expression, like, for example: Double.parseDouble("3*3/5"). =/

Comment: No I meant what you do is store all of them as integers as you normally do and then when you go to do the equation parse them then. Don't parse them as they are pressed because it will then be shown that way. You can also use truncate as well for your view so everything is viewed as an int but the variables are all double. Just all suggestions.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! But I found another problem, the JEXL library gets the expression from a string variable, and then evaluates it to find the answer. The app gets the String variable from the screen (textview), so, if the screen shows "9*9", that's what the JEXL library will use to generate the answer. So, doesn't matter if the variables are stored as double, as long as it appears as integer in the screen. Maybe it would be easy to use the RPN  system (see HP calculators)! haha

Comment: Well, I created a solution, and I think that it's closest to your solution, so I'll accept your answer. I'll edit my post and put it there. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

It will help if all your numbers are of type double, especially your answer. to force a double as your answer, use typecasting or multiply by 1.0 when doing division and multiplication. (literally "1.0", not just "1")

Comment: Well, I can't use double as the user types the numbers, as I explained in the @w9jds comment. And it's pointless to convert the result (which will be an integer) to double, as I would lost the precision. =/

Comment: I would give a similar explanation as was given there. Only use the values as doubles when it comes to calculations. Otherwise, keep as string or whatever you need for your display to look proper. :)

Answer (score -1):

Java by default supports integer arithmetic.
To get the result in float or double(decimal point values),we should perform operation on the float or double data type.
for eg :

```
double x = 3.0/2.0
```

will give you x as **1.5** :)
but,

```
double x = 3/2
```

will give you **1**,which you won't prefer in this case :(
Hope,this helps you

Comment: Read my comment in the @w9jds comment. =/